# iOS Charts LineGraph in Xcode does not show all values. Why?

Tags: xcode, swift, charts, ios-charts

I’m using iOS Charts.framework (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my swift xcodeproject. 
My x-values are dates as String and my y-valus are Double data between 0 and 1000. My test data series size is  392 and it has values greater than 0.0 at over 20 places  but the other dates the values are 0.0 (as seen in the valueArray below). The LineChart graph is only showing 5 values that are > 0.0 (as you can see in the image below). Why?
Is it possible to  get the LineChart to display all values? Or should I use a different chart library?

Here is an image of the Line graph displaying the data in the Array below

[image: Line graph of the valueArray not displaying all the data]

valueArray = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 125.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 75.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 75.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 25.0]

Comment: That did not help. Yes, but... well, I think the graph could have been able to show more than the first  30 values!  Maby Im using the wrong framework...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following code into project which resolve your problem of label of display.

```
       for (id<IChartDataSet> set in chartView.data.dataSets)
        {
            set.drawValuesEnabled = !set.isDrawValuesEnabled;
        }

        [chartView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Yes. I found this good example of what I want https://www.apteligent.com/developer-resources/building-a-native-tvos-dashboard-app/